# Select com atributos repetidos

Tags: html, formulário

Estou com dificuldade em gravar em dois campos diferentes de uma tabela utilizando um `<select>` que possui dois atributos *name* e `<options>` com dois *value*.

Utilizei o código abaixo, porém o mesmo gravou somente o primeiro *name* com seu respectivo *value*:

```
<div align="center" style=" padding:2px; border-right:solid 1px;float:left; width:210px; height:auto; float:left;">
   <?php
       include '../conexao.php';
       $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
       $noticia = $_POST['noticia'];
       $habi_noticia = $_POST['habi_noticia'];
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
       $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

       if(isset($_POST['noti'])){
           $noticia = $_POST['noticia'];
           $habi_noticia = $_POST['habi_noticia'];
           $update = mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET noticia = '$noticia', habi_noticia = '$habi_noticia'");

           if($update == ''){
               echo "
                   <script language='javascript'>
                       window.alert('Erro ao Habilitar Link Noticias!');
                   </script>";
           } else{
               echo "
                   <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
                   <script language='javascript'>
                       window.alert('Link Noticias Habilitado com sucesso!');
                   </script>";
           }
       }
   ?>

   <form name="noti" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label>Habilitar o Link Noticias?</label><br /><br />
       <select name="noticia" | name="habi_noticia" >
           <option value='<li><a href="<?php echo $res['dominio'];?>noticias.php" class="nav1">Noticias</a></li><li class="divider"></li>' | value='Sim'>Sim</option>
           <option value="" | value="Não">Não</option>
       </select><input type="submit" name="noti" value="Atualizar" />
   </form>
</div>
```

---

**É possível gravar dois valores em campos diferentes usando o Select? caso sim, como?**

Comment: de qual select vc ta falando?

Comment: Utilize apenas um value e um name para as tags, com redundância do conteúdo você não vai conseguir capturar os valores corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Existe algumas coisas no seu código que você deva evitar.

- Não definir o mesmo atributo 2 vezes;
- Não utilizar um código muito extenso dentro do atributo;

Um atributo definido 2 vezes terá como válido sempre o último a ser definido, ou seja, o primeiro `value` será ignorado.

Para atingir o seu objetivo, seria mais fácil mover essa verificação para o `backend`, no seu caso para o `PHP`, por exemplo:

```
<select name="noticia>
   <option value="1">Sim</option>
   <option value="2">Não</option>
</select>
```

E dentro do `PHP` você poderia fazer a verificação:

```
if ($noticia == 1) {
    //codigo com link da notícia
} else {
    //Faça a outra definição aqui
};
```

Desse modo fica mais organizado e menos propício a erros.

Comment: Também fica mais seguro. Com o código do exemplo original, pode submeter qualquer valor como "noticia" se mandar um POST fora do site (por exemplo com `curl`). O que accontece se eu mandar um POST ao servidor com um valor "noticia" de `noticias.php'; DROP TABLE menu; --`? SEMPRE verifique dados passados ao servidor.